# Place overlaying div on right bottom corner

Tags: html, css

I'm building an image moderation app.

Each image appears as a tile, and there's a button to approve images, and a button to delete them from the database.

I have been struggling to place the delete button (the one with the 'X') on the bottom right of each tile.

I assume it's something to do with the positioning but I've tried many options but haven't found a solution yet and it's driving me mad.

```
.remove {
position: absolute;
right:0;
bottom:0;
z-index : 0;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
width:40px;
height:40px;
padding-top:2px;
padding-left:5px;
font-size: 2em;}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vgv1trop/1/

Any clues?

edit: Thanks, I was missing position:relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Css like following:

just add `position:relative` to parent `.entry` div, so absolute positioned elements can be placed relative to the parent `<div>`

```
.entry {
    display:inline;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:31%;
    margin: 1.1%;
    position:relative; /* add this */
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgv1trop/3/)